# Metric Tensor and Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I have a doubt about the metric tensor and curvature. My point is: last year I was talking to a mathematician that I know and he said to me that the metric tensor is something that we define on a manifold like an inner product is defined on a vector space.

What he said is: given a vector space $V$ we can define any inner product that we want, it just must comply with the axioms. The same happens with the metric tensor: given a manifold $M$ we can define any metric tensor, it just needs to assign to each point a valid inner product on the tangent space.

But hat brought me some doubts: the $2$-sphere is a manifold $S^2$, and it has curvature. This is obvious geometrically: we can see that $S^2$ cannot be considered flat in any way. However, the curvature tensor which gives the curvature, is defined in terms of the metric. If we can define any metric that we want, then how we're going to recover the "*true*" curvature of the sphere ?

In other words, I think that there wouldn't be a problem to assign to the $S^2$ as a metric tensor the tensor field that at each point assign just the euclidean inner product.

I thought that the metric tensor was derived from the charts, but this mathematician said that it's not, it's just defined at our will, having to satisfy the inner product properties at any point. Can someone point out a good reference for me to read more about how to obtain the metric and so on ? Or even give some example ?

Thanks in advance. And sorry if the question is silly. Also, if it's not well explained, just tell me and I'll rewrite it.

Comment: A submanifold is a special case. $\mathbb R^3$ already has a metric. The inner product of two vectors tangent to $\mathbb S^2$ is understood to be the inner product inherited from the ambient space. One may, however, take a smooth manifold diffeomorphic to $\mathbb S^2$ and supply it with some other metric. In some cases, this is the same result as a distorted sphere in $\mathbb R^3,$ in more extreme cases some higher $\mathbb R^n$ would be required, this being the Nash theorem.

Comment: If this continues to bother you, watch this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCMcu18sigc which will take your mind off it entirely. And it's not even pornographic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is: You can't give $\mathbb{S}^2$ a flat metric, because the metric must be assigned to each point in a *smooth manner*. The different ways in which this can be done are subject to topological constraints. The most famous and elementary example of this is the [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Bonnet_theorem), which says that for any closed surface $S$ and any smooth Riemannian metric $g$ on $S$, its sectional curvature $\kappa_g$ must satisfy
$$\int_S \kappa_g = 2\pi\chi(S).$$
(Here, $\chi(S)$ denotes the [Euler characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) of $S$.)

Comment: I think there must be other constraints on $k_g$ on $S^2$, besides $\int k_g=4\pi$, but I never learned of any. Do you know of any such constraints that are easy to state?

Comment: @Neal I understood the point. It must also be asigned in a smooth manner. But then how the metric can be obtained? I know that when the manifold is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ it's just a question of making a restriction of the euclidean inner product. But what about more general manifolds? Can you point me a reference about this kind of construction? Thanks.

Comment: @5pm, not really, but any sufficiently peculiar metric will raise the necessary $n$ of the $\mathbb R^n$ in which the resulting item can be isometrically embedded.

Comment: @user1620696 From an abstract perspective, you can take any metric you want on any coordinate chart and use a partition of unity to define a global metric.

Comment: @5pm None off the top of my head. Now I'm wondering whether that constraint completely determines the space of metrics on $\mathbb{S}^2$.

Comment: Wait, the integral condition does not make sense since the metric itself is to be determined. The necessary and sufficient condition is for $\kappa$ to be positive *somewhere*. Source: [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122835/possible-curvatures-of-the-topological-sphere).

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of the integral condition as a constraint on the space of metrics, not the space of Gauss curvature maps.

Comment: If one takes 1 dimensional manifolds in 2d then the induced metric is 1 number, corresponding to the speed. Hence in that case one should project a tangent vector at one place on at another place to discover if there is curvature. Hence it gives more information to have the metric tensor defined at a pair of points, since it is a bilinear form.